# How can I make my code work if the input is a tuple?

Tags: python, function, boolean, tuples

So I wrote this code with the help of a few kind Stack Overflow users...

It's trying to **analyze my tuple `l` and see whether for `x` in that tuple**, are their two pairs of the first character in the elements or not

Here is my code,

```
def two_pairs(l):
    d = {}
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        d.setdefault(x[0],[]).append(i)

    for v in d.values():
        if len(v) > 2:
            return False
        elif len(v) == 2:
            if v[1] - v[0] == 1:
                continue
            else:
                return False
        else:
            continue
    return True
```

However, this only works when the input is a list... like

```
['AS', 'AD', 'CC', 'CH', 'CS'] returns False because there are 3 C and 2 , but there are supposed to be 2 of the same elements and one of a completely different element.

['AS', 'AD', 'SC', 'SH', 'CS'] returns True because there are 2 A, 2 S and one C.
['CS', 'CD', 'AC', 'AH', 'FS'] returns True because there are 2 C, 2 A and one F

['AS', 'CD', 'AC', 'CH', 'DS'] returns False because although there are two A, two C and one D, the A and C are not in order
```

However, I want my code to work **when the input `h` is a tuple** like  `('AS', 'CD', 'AC', 'CH', 'DS'])`, and return True or False as well..

What changes should I make??

Comment: Note that there is an extra `]` in the tuple you gave (`('AS', 'CD', 'AC', 'CH', 'DS'])`) so it is not a valid tuple. Removing the `]` might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the following code to convert a `tuple` to a `list` at the top of your function:

```
l = list(l)
```

(If `l` is already a list then this line will have no effect)